# Ripple effect for menu item without icon

Tags: android, xml

How to make a ripple effect for a menu that covers the entire item 'Settings'?

Now ripple effect for menu item without icon looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem with this code

```
  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.WithTextMenuItems" parent="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/bg_ripple_button_rounded</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from my app:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apply_button"
        style="@style/MyTextButtonTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
        android:text="@string/apply"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_button_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/up_navigation_imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/up_navigation_imageButton" />
```

And this goes in styles.xml:

```
<!-- Change ripple color on TextButtons -->
<style name="MyTextButtonTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="rippleColor">?attr/colorOnBackgroundMediumContrast</item>
</style>
```

https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't like to make custom toolbar

Comment: Sorry then, I have no idea. I gave up on the built-in toolbar almost immediately. It's not hard to add your own.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your xml view

```
<TextView
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
  android:clickable="true"/>
```